# Capturing scope in directive while it's digesting—far more verbose than a console.log(scope)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've been using a directive with `scope: false` to investigate what's available to a directive that has access to its parent's scope—I just now realized that doing a `console.log(scope)` in the linking function has been somewhat misleading.

```
.directive('directive', function() {
    return {
        scope: false;
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(scope); 
            console.log($.extend({}, scope));
        }
});
```

The latter, `console.log($.extend({}, scope));`, is an object that is far more verbose, I assume this is being logged during the `$digest` phase, (as one of the properties, `$$phase`, has a value of `$digest` :-P).

The `console.log($.extend({}, scope));` also includes objects which I would expect to have access to from the parent scope, like objects on the parent scope, which don't appear in the output from `console.log(scope)`.

So I'm now assuming that the `console.log($.extend({}, scope));`—actually is housing what is available to `scope` in the directive's linking function.

Anyways, what is going on with `console.log(scope)`—what is it showing me exactly, and why are the two different?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Here is an example of the output from both:

[image: the more verbose scope is the first output.]

I notice they have different prototypes, but not sure what exactly to derive from that. Because of this, it's kind of murky as to what is actually available in a directive's scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really related to $digests.

```
var verboseObject = $.extend({}, scope);
console.log(verboseObject);
```

The above is more verbose because all the properties from Angular's `Scope` prototype (which `scope` inherits from) got copied to `verboseObject`. This is just the way jQuery's `$.extend` works: 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

> properties inherited from the object's prototype will be copied over

Since those properties are not on the `verboseObject` prototype but on the object itself, Developer Tools just shows it like a flat object.

```
console.log(scope);
```

In the above case, all the "missing" properties like `$digest`, `$apply`, `$eval` and so on are still available on `scope`, just further up the prototype chain. In Developer Tools you can inspect the prototype chain by expanding the `__proto__` property of an object. You might have to go up a few times to reach the actual `Scope` that `scope` inherits from.